# How to solve DSolve[y'[x] == a Sin[x], y[xo] == 0, y[x], x]

Tags: differential-equations

How to solve with initial value that is parameter y[xo] == 0

```
 DSolve[y'[x] == a Sin[x], y[xo] == 0, y[x], x]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need list brackets around the equations

```
eqns = {y'[x] == a Sin[x], y[x0] == 0};

soln = DSolve[eqns, y, x][[1]]

(*  {y -> Function[{x}, -a Cos[x] + a Cos[x0]]}  *)
```

Verifying the solution

```
eqns /. soln

(*  {True, True}  *)
```

Comment: Thanks! How to do it with system of equations http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120316/how-to-solve-couple-diffrential-equation-in-closed-form

Comment: x''[t]==-a0*(a1 - b*z'[t])*Cos[w*t]

z''[t]=-a0*b*x'[t]*Cos[w*t]

This gives an error:

eqn1 = {x''[t] == -a0*(a1 - b*z'[t])*Cos[w*t], x[t0] == 0, x'[t0] == 0};
eqn2 = {z''[t] == -a0*b*x'[t]*Cos[w*t], z[t0] == 0, z'[t0] == 0};

soln = DSolve[{eqn1, eqn2}, {x,z}, t][[1]]

Comment: @Anonymous - in your comment, there are several spaces missing (e.g., bz'[t], bx'[t], wt). Also, the first argument to `DSolve` should be a list of equations (e.g., `{eqn1, eqn2}//Flatten`). However, even with corrections, `DSolve` cannot solve this system. You will need to assign values to the constants and use `NDSolve`. You could assign the values of the constants with controls in a `Manipulate` so that you can readily investigate how the constants influence the output.